# Is it possible to draw a pattern (XABCD) on embed Tradingview widget?

Tags: javascript, widget

I want to draw an **xabcd shape** on an **embed tradingview chart** using javascript.

I searched a lot but I not found any working way.

please help me to solve my problem

May I can inject some pinescript if javascript is not possible ?

```
    <script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script>
    var options = {
        symbol: "BINANCE:KNCBTC",
        interval: "60",
        container: "ata-tradeview-widget-modal",
    }
    
    
    tv = new TradingView.widget(options);
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @saeid-ezzati, did you found a solution ?

Comment: hi @JérémieChazelle. no finally I used main tradingview library sources files and host them on my server. get library source from here: [TradingView Charting Library standalone](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?feature=technical-analysis-charts)

Comment: Hi @saeidezzati, could you draw a line on tradingView chart by this library?